# deploy spray with akka on tomcat 7 , cannot get response from RestAPI

Tags: scala, tomcat, tomcat7, akka, spray

I am trying to deploy my app on tomcat. I am getting to my index.html but my API respond

> 404 not found

And I can't figure out what am I doing wrong

this is my service actor

```
class DemoRoute extends Actor with DemoRouteService {
  implicit def actorRefFactory: ActorContext = context
  def receive = runRoute(route)
}

trait DemoRouteService extends HttpService{

  val route = {
    import com.tr.em.domain.JsonImplicits._
     path("foo"/"status"){
          get{
            complete("I feel good, thanks for checking")
          }
        }
    }
}
```

This my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>spray.servlet.Initializer</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SprayConnectorServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>spray.servlet.Servlet30ConnectorServlet</servlet-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SprayConnectorServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

this is my application.conf

```
akka {
  loglevel = INFO
  event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
}

spray.servlet {
  boot-class = "com.tr.em.SprayBoot"
  request-timeout = 10s
}
```

this is my boot class

```
import spray.servlet.WebBoot
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props

class SprayBoot extends WebBoot {
  val system = ActorSystem("systemactor")
  val serviceActor = system.actorOf(Props[DemoRoute])
  system.registerOnTermination {
    system.log.info("Application shut down")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From spray-servlet documentation

> # The class must have a constructor with a single
>     # `javax.servlet.ServletContext` parameter and implement
>     # the `spray.servlet.WebBoot` trait.
>
> boot-class = ""

Looks like your class does not have appropriate constructor

Answer (score 0):

Solved. it was a kind of a race condition .
had to add logs to see the real error . anyway I had to add define the service actor as lazy

```
lazy val serviceActor = system.actorOf(Props[DemoRoute])
```